# why do I get "wait_fences: failed to receive reply" for this code?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsthread, nsnotifications, nsnotificationcenter

why do I get "wait_fences: failed to receive reply" for this code?  Is it the way I'm using notification to communicate back to the main thread?

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize  alert;


#pragma mark - Background Thread Test Methods

- (void) ConfigTasksForBackground:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"ConfigTasksForBackground - Starting");
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:6];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ModelChanged" object:self];
    NSLog(@"ConfigTasksForBackground - Ending");
}

#pragma mark - Callbacks

- (void) ModelChangedHandler:(NSNotification *) notification {
    if ([[notification name] isEqualToString:@"ModelChanged"]) {
        NSLog(@"ModelChangedHandler");
        [self.alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:false];
    }
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(ModelChangedHandler:) 
                                                 name:@"ModelChanged"
                                               object:nil];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    self.alert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" 
                                                    message:@"viewDidAppear" 
                                                   delegate:nil 
                                          cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil] autorelease];
    [alert show];
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(ConfigTasksForBackground:) withObject:nil];
}



@end
```

Output is:

```
2011-11-07 15:15:42.730 test_background[6876:13603] ConfigTasksForBackground - Starting
2011-11-07 15:15:48.734 test_background[6876:13603] ModelChangedHandler
2011-11-07 15:15:49.236 test_background[6876:13603] ConfigTasksForBackground - Ending
wait_fences: failed to receive reply: 10004003
```

Comment: Check the SO post ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4241894/wait-fences-failed-to-receive-reply-10004003-error-uialert-without-uitextfie

Comment: didn't fix it actually - the wait_fences occurs after the "ModelChangedHandler" is triggered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to get rid of the wait_fences error. Change the line where you dismiss the alertView to use animation as follows:

```
[self.alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
```

I think wait_fences has something to do with view animation states with alert views but it's hard to know for sure. I do think this should eliminate the error msg though. My other answer doesn't directly get rid of the error but I still recommend it. UI actions should be done on the main thread.

Answer (score 3):

There is an obvious problem here. You are posting the notification from the background thread (which is fine) which means the notification handler `ModelChangedHandler` is being called on the background thread. The handler is then dismissing an alert view which must be done on the main thread. Try changing your code to:

```
- (void) ModelChangedHandler:(NSNotification *) notification {
    if (![NSThread isMainThread]) {
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(ModelChangedHandler:) withObject:notification waitUntilDone:NO];
    }

    else if ([[notification name] isEqualToString:@"ModelChanged"]) {
        NSLog(@"ModelChangedHandler");
        [self.alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:false];
    }
}
```

EDIT: was typing too fast, changed answer to reflect the correct UI objects.

Comment: thanks - interestly it didn't seem to fix it....but I see what you mean, and I can the performSelectorOnMainThread getting run first, so your code makes sense.  Just that I still get the "wait_fences" line at the end.  BY THE WAY your info here kind of points out the response I got here might be wrong  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8032652/is-it-ok-to-use-of-a-notification-to-communication-back-to-the-main-thread-of-an

Comment: uh. I wrote both answers. I don't think they are contradictory. The wait_fences error may be caused by something else by my comment re: threads and UI operations needing to be on the main thread is correct.