# Is NSNotificationCenter thread safe?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, concurrency, grand-central-dispatch, nsnotificationcenter

Can I post a notification in a given queue and receive it on another?  I want to use notifications to communicate different queues, but I'm not sure if this is safe...

Comment: you can use it, but there are some advances solutions to synchronise the different threads as well like semaphores, locks etc...

Comment: It sounds like your essentially asking the same question as [I answered here.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13484491/927947)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No.  Notifications are delivered in the same thread that they are sent from, this you will need to re-send it in some way to get the notification to your thread.

Answer (score 15):

No.

Apple's docs on the subject say: "*Regular notification centers deliver notifications on the thread in which the notification was posted. [...] At times, you may require notifications to be delivered on a particular thread that is determined by you instead of the notification center. [...] In these cases, you must capture the notifications as they are delivered on the default thread and redirect them to the appropriate thread.*"

The following documentation from Apple might help: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Articles/Threading.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001289-CEGJFDFG